# how to inner join two tables or more tables from ms access database with vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

I have three tables in access database and a Application in vb.net where i am trying to search data from all three tables by TextBox but it is giving error.can someone tell me how to do this?

```
enter code here
```

Private Sub check()

```
    Dim Myconn As New OleDbConnection(constr)
    Dim adapter As New OleDbDataAdapter()
    Dim command As New OleDbCommand()
    Dim sql = "select descriptionofgoods,remarks,mode from tabel1 INNER JOIN table2 ON tabel1.id = tabel2.id inner join tabel3 on tabel1.id = tabel3.id;"
    Try
        Myconn.Open()
        dt.Clear()
        If TextBox2.Text > "" Then
            sql = sql & " and  [id] = ? "
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("id", TextBox1.Text)
        End If
        command.Connection = Myconn
        command.CommandText = sql
        adapter.SelectCommand = command
        adapter.Fill(dt)
        If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
            DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
            DataGridView1.Refresh()
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("ITEM NOT FOUND")
        End If
    Catch exp As Exception
        Throw exp
    Finally
        If Myconn IsNot Nothing Then Myconn.Close()
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Your sql string ends with a semi-colon so you can't just concatenate an additional string to it. But you don't need an "and", you need a Where clause.

Comment: Also you have both 'table2' and 'tabel2' in your join

Comment: And exactly what error is it giving you, where is the error occurring?  Have you stepped through your code checking the state at each point to ensure it is as expected?

Answer (score 0):

A lot of your code is redundant and can be removed:

```
    Using da as New OleDbDataAdapter("select descriptionofgoods,remarks,mode from tabel1 INNER JOIN table2 ON tabel1.id = tabel2.id inner join tabel3 on tabel1.id = tabel3.id", constr)

        Dim dt = DirectCast(DataGridView1.DataSource, DataTable)
        dt.BeginLoadData()
        dt.Clear()

        If Not string.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox2.Text) Then
            da.SelectCommand.CommandText &= " and tabel1.[id] = ? " 
            da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("id", TextBox1.Text) 'why is this TextBox1 when you tested textbox2 in the If?
        End If

        adapter.Fill(dt)
        dt.EndLoadData()
    End Using
```

Notes:

- Use Using; you then don't need your Try/Finally
- DataAdapter knows how to create and open a connection itself
- Don't catch exceptions only to throw them again; it disrupts the stack trace. Dont put a catch at all if youre not going to catch anything; `Try ... Finally` is legal, `Throw` on its own is legal (doesn't disrupt stack trace)
- Do not terminate an SQL with a semicolon if you want to add to it. Don't terminate a single statement SQL with a semicolon anyway
- You have several tables with an ID column; Access might let you get away with not specifying which ID you're talking about but proper databases won't so get in the habit now of fully qualifying every column (in your select too)
- See the comment about TextBox1/TextBox2
- Please.. name your controls properly. "name of a type of object plus a serial number" is not a good name for anything; your name is Pankaj Babbar, not human105874274365. You name your local variables well but not your class level ones, which is *definitely* the wrong way round
- To rename a control after you add it to a windows form, click on it, then change then text in the (Name) line of the property grid
- Telling a datatable youre about to/have finished loading data improves performance
- Bound controls update automatically (if you ever use BindingSource investigate the RaiseListChangedEvents setting too)

Comment: Just beware of using Parameters.AddWithValue(), you're quite likely to get unexpected and invalid type casts and in some situations you may get away with it, there are plenty it will cause problems

Comment: Caius Jard its not working.  da.SelectCommand &= " and GIVE_A_TABLE_NAME_HERE.[id] = ? "  it is giving operator & is not definded for oledb command and string. .

Comment: @Hursey Joel's blog is aimed at SQL Server. This is not SQL Server. AddWithValue is not a universal evil; please see https://mysqlconnector.net/overview/using-addwithvalue/

Comment: @pankajbabbar I changed the code. ps, your code shouldn't say `GIVE_A_TABLE_NAME_HERE` because you were supposed to replace that string with a table name. Please ensure you always *read and understand* what people post for you on StackOverflow, [don't just blindly copy off SO and paste into your code](https://www.theverge.com/tldr/2016/5/4/11593084/dont-get-busted-copying-code-from-stack-overflow). I've amended it for you, because all the id are the same, but you still should read the comment on the line underneath

Comment: Sir my tabel name is tabel1 and  I have already changed table name to da.SelectCommand &= " tabel1.[id] = ? " But it is giving error giving operator & is not definded for oledb command and string.

Comment: OK, but did you check the edit to the code? It should say `da.SelectCommand.CommandText &= " and tabel1.[id] = ? "` (adding .CommandText). Also not sure why you removed the AND from the string - it is needed to prevent an SQL syntax error

Comment: no sir i have checked what you had told me. i put my tabel name in code and not removed and from it. but it is showing red line below code and showing operator & is not defined for oledb commands and string.